# Status of Usage Metrics - Is it dead or is there a roadmap?

Tags: isv, usagemetrics

The current version of **Salesforce Usage Metrics** for ISV apps as describe here https://www.salesforce.com/video/192805/ is quite limited and seems to suffer from a lot issues.

[image]

Is this a dead tool that will not be improved by Salesforce anymore? Or is there a roadmap to improve the tooling ([current Appexchange app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5FMvEAN)) and feature set (track more app metrics like Lightning and code usage)?

Comment: This is by no means an answer, but did you know that you can at least query the `MetricsDataFile` object? I've had to write a few snippets of code that I've run in the Developer Console to get at some of our statistics because the UI stopped working for us. [Some documentation can be found here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_metricsdatafile.htm)

Comment: I cannot answer to the specifics of the metrics API. The [Feature Management App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_manage_features.htm) would enable you to build your own metrics. I just checked with the metrics [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/usage_metrics_intro.htm): You could achieve both features with Feature Management as well.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp I'm not sure how the upcomming FMA should allow me to measure how many records Customer X has of Custom Object Z. Or what the 5 most used Vf pages are.

Comment: @RobertSösemann You would need to create your own logic to accomplish that, i.e. collect, then write metrics when user clicks a button / reads a VF page. The latter is straightforward. To hide a [select count() from object__c] somewhere in your codebase seems feasible to me. 
'Tracking' is explicitly referenced in the docs: [Track Preferences and Activation Metrics with Subscriber-to-LMO Feature Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_subscriber_to_lmo.htm)

Comment: Found another repo that illustrates various use-cases: https://github.com/forcedotcom/project-force

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the repo. FMA tracking is not the right technology to solve my problems even if there would be hacks to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an area where, unfortunately, we've not been able to actively invest. It is top of mind, however, and something that we feel we can address soon in the future.

Comment: I just watched this interesting DF17 talk about how Salesforce internally tracks/instruments Lightning usage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxz3EK1nC40 Will this one day merge into Usage Metrics?